# Get data sent from form in popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

I need to Get data sent from form in popup but the problem that in the form there is many checkboxes with same name like `name='list[]'` :

**JS :**

```
function showPopup(){
    var user = document.getElementById("check").value;
    var popup = window.open("milestone.php?a="+user,"hhhhhh","width=440,height=300,top=100,left=‌​300,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1") ;
}
```

**html :**

```
<input type='checkbox' name="approve[]" value="get from Mysql">
<input type='checkbox' name="approve[]" value="get from Mysql"> 
<input type='checkbox' name="approve[]" value="get from Mysql">
```

Comment: You should add some code to your question

Comment: Ok see this
Javascript :
function showPopup(){
    var user = document.getElementById("check").value;
    
var popup = window.open("milestone.php?a="+user,"hhhhhh","width=440,height=300,top=100,left=300,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1")
}
html :
<input type='checkbox' name="approve[]" value="get from Mysql">
<input type='checkbox' name="approve[]" value="get from Mysql">
<input type='checkbox' name="approve[]" value="get from Mysql">
..............
many other line with same name

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you talking about server side end? If yes, which server side language you are using? Is it PHP, Asp.net or node.js???

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed you could see the PHP tag in the OP.

Comment: @NoGodButAllah you want ot pass the values to `milestone.php` via link?

Comment: Im using php but first I want to sent form data to popup window

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the array via get you should loop through all the checked checkboxes and store the value of everyone in array then convert them to Json using `JSON.stringify` so you can passe them in url :

```
function showPopup(){
    var approve_array=[];
    var checked_checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

    for(var i=0;i<all_checkboxes.length;i++){
        approve_array[i] = checked_checkboxes[i].value;
    }

    var url = "milestone.php?approve="+JSON.stringify(approve_array);

    var popup = window.open(url,"hhhhhh","width=440,height=300,top=100,left=‌​300,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1") ;
}
```

In you php page you could get the array passed as Json using `json_decode` :

```
$array_of_approves = json_decode($_GET['approve']);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var user = document.getElementById("check").value;
> ```

That won't work because:

- You need to get multiple values
- You need to get the values only of checkboxes that have been checked
- You don't have an element with that id (but an id has to be unique anyway)

The fields all have the same name. Use the name.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("approve[]")
```

Then you need to generate your form data from it, filtering out the ones which are not checked:

```
var form_data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    if (input.checked) {
        form_data.push(encodeURIComponent(input.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(input.value));
    }
}
```

Then put all the form data together:

```
var form_data_query_string = form_data.join("&");
```

Then put it in your URL:

```
var url = "milestone.php" + "?" + form_data_query_string;
```

Then open the new window:

```
var popup = window.open(url,"hhhhhh","width=440,height=300,top=100,left=‌​300,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1") ;
```

Comment: Quentin thats realy work fine but How I get the values the url in popup look like this
milestone.php?approve[]=TIM16-0012&approve[]=TIM16-0010

Comment: @NoGodButAllah — `$_GET['approve']`

Answer (score -1):

You can access the value as:

```
    $approveList= $_POST['approve'];
```

and can be iterated as

```
    foreach ($approveList as $approve){
     echo $approve."<br />";
           }
```